# Need to fix user accounts

Tags: release-hera, user

After creating a non-admin user, I could no longer change admin user's password.  Had to login to non-admin user's account and change admin from there, after entering admin password.  Definite bug.

Recreate: Create non-admin account, try to change admin account password.
Next: Login to non-admin account, authenticate to change admin account, easily change password for admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this a symptom of the same underlying issue as this: [Standard user can inhibit admin user from suspending computer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29932/standard-user-can-inhibit-admin-user-from-suspending-computer)

> Summary: User A (std user) and User B (admin) both logged in. User A can suspend the computer whenever. User B cannot suspend the computer until User A logs out of their current session.
>
> However, I would expect if User A (std) can suspend the computer, then User B (admin) should also be equally able to suspend the computer?